# Emulator for Digi-Comp I

Tags: emulator

I'm looking for an emulator for [Digi-Comp I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digi-Comp_I).
I can't find one. All I've found is this Turing train thing. Any Help? I'm trying to see if I can recreate the classic toy.

Comment: Probably wrong place to ask. I had a Digicomp1 when I was a kid. It basically is a finite state automaton implemented by mechanical hardware

Comment: For what operating system?

Answer (score 3):

Larry Groebe and I developed a Digi-Comp I emulator in HTML and Javascript in 1999.  It's been hosted in various places and disappeared for a while.  I recently resurrected it and moved it to the Google Cloud Platform.

Here's the URL:  http://digicomp-1.appspot.com/